# Maximum value of an integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

Max value of $$\int_{a-1}^{a+1} \frac{1}{1+ x^8} \,dx$$is attained at what value of a?

My attempt:

Let the given integral be $\alpha$ . Then the max value can be calculated by differentiating the term. So for differentiating, i used the Newton-Leibniz rule but all i could infer from the result was that the function $\alpha$ is monotonous. I don't know what else to do. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The function is actually decreasing for $a>0$ and increasing for $a<0$. Hence the maximum is attained at $a=0$.

Comment: Oh yes , i see it now. Thank you.